# php - search TXT file by users $_post from form

Tags: php, forms, file, post, input

Im having a little problem.

I have a txt file that i can write users names.
Thats ok!

But im  trying to search the txt file by user input ($_POST['username']).
I getting user do not exist all the time..

anyone that can give me some tips?

My txt file contains:


**Admin

Sheldon

Penny**

Here is the code:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];

function CreateAccount($user){

if($_POST['reg']){

    $file = 'test.txt';
    $data = $user ."\n";
    fopen($file, 'a');
    file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);

}


}

function userSearch($user){

if($_POST['read']){

    $file = 'test.txt';
    $searchUser = $user;
    fopen($file, 'r');
    $content = file_get_contents($file);

    if(strpos($content, $user)){
        echo "exist";
    }else{
        echo "nope..";
    }

}
}
```

Comment: looks like a job for a db to me

Comment: this is just a little experiment on how to read from text file by users posts.

Comment: i would perhaps use `file()` and then `in_array()` myself

Comment: I would go with Dagon's method too, but in this case why not use strstr()?

Comment: You also don't have to fopen file before file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

String positions with `strpos` start at 0 not 1. So if the position is 0 it will equate to false.

Simple fix for your if statement may help

`if(strpos($content, $user) !== FALSE){`

[PHP strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos)

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: For 100% accuracy then check against boolean false instead: `if(strpos($content, $user) !== false)`

Comment: Could do, I just got into the habit years ago of checking it was > -1

Comment: i tried with if(strpos($content, $user) !== false) but im still getting "nope.."

Comment: Check this [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hiw-7ft) for an example. I replaced the file read with a string representation of what would be in the file.

Comment: Thanks for youre answers!
it works fine with at string representation but i want it to work with tha name that the user have posted from the form.

Comment: Then all you need to do is replace `userSearch('suzanne');` with the actual post data `$_POST['username']`

Comment: I understand but it is irresponsible to spread bad habits to new (or even experienced) programmers especially since `-1` is an integer so it should be respected as such. Boolean `TRUE` and `FALSE` exist for a reason so I highly recommend respecting the docs which you quoted `This function may return Boolean FALSE`, thanks! `x>-1 !== boolean false`

Answer (score -1):

**t.txt:**

> Admin
> Sheldon
> Leonard

**t.php**

```
<?php
$file = "t.txt";
$name = "Sheldon";
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$array = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if(in_array($name,$array)){
    echo "found ";
}else{
    echo "nope ";
}

if(strstr($string,$name)){
    echo "found ";
}else{
    echo "nope ";
}
?>
```

**output:**
`found found`

Comment: Probably because this is just you giving some code and not a structured answer or informative help. Also it is best to avoid closing php tags if the file contains only php, to avoid whitespace injection. Your answer also replaces the code of the OP and doesn't help them with their original code.